# React Native Built Failed

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native

```
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Install\ Third\ Party /Users/iChep/Documents/Coding/React\ Native\ Apps/albums/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/Script-190EE32F1E6A43DE00A8543A.sh
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/albums.app
No devices are booted.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/albums.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

I get this issues when trying to built my react native application. I know that this issue is a common one, but I'm trying to solve since 10 hours and I tryed nearly every solution on the Facebook Trubleshooting page and on the github issue page. I'm really frustrated and would appreciate the help.

I'm using Node: 8.1.2,

XCode: 8.3.3,

npm: 5.0.3,

react-native-cli: 2.0.1,

react-native: 0.45.1

Comment: Did you connect your iPhone through USB?

Answer (score 0):

When nothing fixes, try on Xcode

1. Go to File -> Project settings
2. Click the Advanced button
3. Select "Custom" and select "Relative to Workspace" in the pull down
   click done, done

[image]

The reference is [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308#issuecomment-230198331) on GitHub.